# Как расположить элементы в ряд, что бы у input был сплошной border?

Tags: css3, html5

Не могу решить проблему.
Нужно провести валидацию input type="email". Это нужно сделать средствами html, css. Сам макет необходимо расположить с помощью grid. При валидном вводе должен засветится зелёный border-bottom полностью. У меня выходит как на картинке. Вопрос состоит в том, если элемент слева от input назначить с помощью :before, то как тогда работать с этим элементом в javascript, а если border подсвечивать у родителя input (label), то как это сделать через css файл ?

Здесь код html:

```
<div class="container mx-auto flex flex-col">
        <header>
            <img class="h-12 w-12 mx-auto my-12" src="src/img/abler-logo.svg" alt="logo">
        </header>
        <main class="flex-auto">
            <h1 class="text-lg font-semibold px-6 tracking-tight">Welcome</h1>
            <form method="POST">
                <label for="email" class="flex items-center border-b">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 ml-6 text-grey-50" fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z" />
                    </svg>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full py-3 px-1 outline-none placeholder:text-sm font-semibold placeholder:text-grey-50
                    text-xs" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    <div class="relative py-2">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            class="tick h-6 w-6 inline text-green-50 absolute right-4 top-0 hidden" fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7" />
                        </svg>

                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            class="cross h-6 w-6 text-red-50 absolute right-4 top-0 hidden" fill="none"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 label>input[type="email"]:valid,
    label>input[type="password"]:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5ab98c;
    }
```

[image: Valid]

Comment: Куча способов... Вы можете поставить иконку поверх поля ввода, а полю добавить внутренний отступ слева. Либо использовать правило flex-direction:row-reverse в сочетании с комбинатором следующего соседнего элемента (input:valid + svg)... Есть еще св-во order для подобных целей и т.д. Сделайте нормальный воспроизводимый снипет кода, если хотите готовый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно обязательно оставить svg внутри html, а валидацию делать средствами браузера, я бы сместил иконку внутрь поля. Тогда подчеркивание захватывало бы и иконку (я так понял, именно это вам нужно).

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  border: none;
  
}

label>input[type="email"]:valid,
    label>input[type="password"]:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5ab98c;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="text-lg font-semibold px-6 tracking-tight">Welcome</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    <label>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 ml-6 text-grey-50" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z" />
      </svg>

      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full py-3 px-1 outline-none placeholder:text-sm font-semibold placeholder:text-grey-50 text-xs" placeholder="Email address" required>
    </label>
  </form>
</header>
```